# PSU under 100€ an entry level server

Tags: smps

I'm going to buy this motherboard: **[Supermicro X10SLH-F](https://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/xeon/c220/x10slh-f.cfm)**.
The **[motherboard manual](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/C222/MNL-1464.pdf)** says (at page 20) "Also your power supply must supply 1.5A for the Ethernet ports". Is a normal ATX power supply enough?.

What ATX/MicroATX PSU would you recommend?

I can't buy from Newegg (it doesn't ship to Italy) and i prefer something available on Amazon (.it or .co.uk, not .com). 
The entire setup will require about 140 Watt and it should be as silent as possible.

---

**EDIT:** I mailed to SuperMicro and they said they only support their chassis and power supplies. But their power supplies "seems" normal power supplies (same cables and same voltages).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the [Super Flower Golden Silent PSU](https://www.amazon.it/Super-Flower-Golden-Fanless-Netzteil/dp/B00H5DAEOW/254-5840332-7707302?ie=UTF8&tag=pcp06-21), available on Amazon.it. It is quite literally silent because it has no fan. Important specifications follow:

- 0dbm
- 80+ Gold efficiency rating
- 430W capacity
- Part number: SF-430P14FG
- Has the 4+4 and 20+4 power connectors needed for this motherboard.